# how to mark a selected menu item using stilearn css

Tags: css

I've inherited a project that is using stilearn css.
It provides styling for menus and one of the features is marking a selected menu button with a small white triangle, as shown in the screenshot attached.

Example of this in action is here:
http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0TFD2S0

Basically how is this done?  I'm using I.E. Dom explorer and cannot figure it out.  (It may turn out to be done using some other css - there is a whole bunch of it).  I can see that the css style "active" is applied to the `<li>` item.

[image: example.]

Answer (score 0):

The `<ul class="sidebar">` element has `<li>` list elements that can be defined as active. When a list item is active `<li class="active">`, it gets that white triangle.

The trick itself is done by using borders on `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. See more on that matter here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 0):

Here try this CSS

```
.sidebar>li.active:before {
    border-color: rgba(204,204,204,0);
    border-right-color: #E0E4E8;
    border-width: 11px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -11px;
}

.sidebar>li.active:after, .sidebar>li.active:before {
    right: -1px;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```